# How do I get the specflow to create a template for a new step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, specflow

When I select a step and hit the "go to step definition" dialog box appears that says "No matching step binding found".

Is it possible to have that step definition automatically created when it is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SpecFlow 1.9 now supports this.** If you have installed the SpecFlow Visual Studio Extension, you can right-click from within a feature file and choose "Generate Step Definitions". It will ask you which steps to create, and what file to place them in.

See the [What's New in v1.9](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/WhatsNew19.html) page for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest SpecFlow Visual Studio integration, then the second part of the message in the dialog box says: "Do you want to copy the step binding skeleton into the clipboard?".

If you press "Yes" the code skeleton of the step definition is copied into clipboard and you can paste it into your step definition file.

Alternatively SpecFlow also outputs the step definition code skeleton for missing steps when executing the scenario:
-> No matching step definition found for the step. Use the following code to create one: 
...((code skeleton for step definition))...

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version and see the second part.

But I want to specflow insert code by itself in *StepDefinition.cs in case of miss definition.

Comment: SpecFlow doesn't do that. And since you anyway need to structure your step definitions and think about where to put them, and also need to manually implement the step definition, I don't see too much value if SpecFlow would automatically add empty step definition skeletons somewhere to your code (ie StepDefinition.cs).